# Как хранить обычные файлы рядом с Tails

Tags: linux, live-usb

У меня есть флешка на 32гб. Хочу сделать так, чтобы под систему с Persistent было выделено 16гб, а остальная память была в обычном FAT32, который можно будет прочитать с винды. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Винда не читает fat со второго раздела на флешках. Только с первого.

Лучший вариант это установочный образ записать на fat32 (через Руфус какой-нибудь) а перстстент сделать в файле.  Как на убунту 12 было. Но надо смотреть умеет ли современный установщик персистент в файл.